# Base 64 encoder on localhost?

Tags: php, syntax

I've placed this script on my localhost but it appears to be malformed (should display an input field for encoding and one for decoding base64.

The author's site has apparently gone dark. Any ideas how to fix it or get a new one?

```
<?
// PHP OBFUSCATOR
// (C)2003 Richard Fairthorne -- http://richard.fairthorne.is-a-geek.com
// --------------------------
// Permission is granted to disctibute this file UNMODIFIED from its original
// form. All other rights are reserved.

function splitByNewline($string, $length) {
    while (strlen($string)>0) {
    $newstring.=substr($string, 0, $length) . "\n";
    $string=substr($string, $length);
    }
  return $newstring;
}

echo "<big><b>Free Code Obfuscator (PHP, PERL)</b></big><br>By <a href='http://richard.fairthorne.is-a-geek.com'>Richard Fairthorne</a><hr>";

$b64_input=stripslashes($b64_input);
switch($b64_action) {
    case "perl_encode":
      $output=$b64_input;
         $output=base64_encode($output);
    $output=splitByNewline($output,40);
    $output="#!/usr/bin/perl\nuse MIME::Base64;\neval(decode_base64('\n$output'));";

    $ilength=strlen($b64_input);
    $olength=strlen($output);

    ?>
    <table border=0 width=100%><tr><td valign=top>
    <textarea rows=18 cols=60 name=done><?=$output;?></textarea>
    </td><td valign=top>
    <b>PERL code obfuscated!</b><br><br>

    Your PERL code has been obfuscated. 
    <br><br>
    <font color=maroon>
    Obfuscation-Strength: Normal (Fast code execution)<br>
    Compatibility: 100% Code compatibility<br>
    Input Length: <?=$ilength;?><br>
    Output Length: <b><?=$olength;?></b><br>
    </font>
    <br>
    To use the code, simply cut and paste it in place of the old code. You may need to update the perl path.
    It is important to understand that code obfuscation can act as a deterrant, but is not a replacement
    for encryption.<br><br>

    <a href='?'>Click here</a> to obfuscate another page.
    </td></tr></table>
    <?
  break;
    case "php_encode":
      $output=$b64_input;
         $output=gzdeflate("?>".$output."<?",9);
         $output=base64_encode($output);
    $output=splitByNewline($output,40);
    $output="<? eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('\n$output'))); ?>";

    $ilength=strlen($b64_input);
    $olength=strlen($output);

    ?>
    <table border=0 width=100%><tr><td valign=top>
    <textarea rows=18 cols=60 name=done><?=$output;?></textarea>
    </td><td valign=top>
    <b>PHP code obfuscated!</b><br><br>

    Your PHP code has been obfuscated. 
    <br><br>
    <font color=maroon>
    Obfuscation-Strength: Normal (Fast code execution)<br>
    Compatibility: Zlib Required. 100% Code compatibility<br>
    Input Length: <?=$ilength;?><br>
    Output Length: <b><?=$olength;?></b><br>
    </font>
    <br>
    To use the code, simply cut and paste it in place of the old code.
    It is important to understand that code obfuscation can act as a deterrant, but is not a replacement
    for encryption.<br><br>

    <a href='?'>Click here</a> to obfuscate another page.
    </td></tr></table>
    <?
  break;
    case "php_encode_hi":
      $output=$b64_input;
    for ($b64_counter=0; $b64_counter<10; $b64_counter++) {
          $output=gzdeflate("?>".$output."<?",9);
          $output=base64_encode($output);
      $output="<? eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('$output'))); ?>";
    }
        $output=gzdeflate("?>".$output."<?",9);
        $output=base64_encode($output);
    $output="<? eval(gzinflate(base64_decode('\n$output'))); ?>";

    $ilength=strlen($b64_input);
    $olength=strlen($output);

    ?>

    <table border=0 width=100%><tr><td valign=top>
    <textarea rows=18 cols=60 name=done><?=$output;?></textarea>
    </td><td valign=top>
    <b>PHP code obfuscated!</b><br><br>

    Your PHP code has been obfuscated. 
    <br><br>
    <font color=maroon>
    Obfuscation-Strength: Trecherous (Best Protection)<br>
    Compatibility: Zlib Required. 100% Code Compatibility.<br>
    Input Length: <?=$ilength;?><br>
    Output Length: <b><?=$olength;?></b><br>
    </font>
    <br>
    To use the code, simply cut and paste it in place of the old code.
    It is important to understand that code obfuscation can act as a deterrant, but is not a replacement
    for encryption.<br><br>

    <a href='?'>Click here</a> to obfuscate another page.
    </td></tr></table>
    <?
  break;
  // case "decode":
  //     $output=htmlentities(base64_decode($b64_input),ENT_QUOTES);
  // break;
  default:
    ?>
    <table border=0 width=100%><tr><td valign=top>
    <form method=post>
    <textarea  name=b64_input cols=60 rows=16></textarea><br>
    <SELECT name=b64_action>
    <OPTION value='php_encode'>PHP - Normal Strength - Compressed</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='php_encode_hi'>PHP - Trecherous Strength - Compressed</OPTION>
    <OPTION value='perl_encode'>PERL - Normal Strength</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    <input type=submit name=submit value='obfuscate'>
    <!-- <input type=submit name=b64_action value=decode> -->
    </form>
    </td><td valign=top>
    <b>Free Code obfuscator</b><br><br>

    If you would like a quick way to hide your php code from prying eyes, try this PHP code obfuscator.<br><br>Copy an entire PHP page, into the obfuscator, and it will return a code that also works on any PHP server, but is not human readable.<br><br>

        With code 5k or bigger, you may notice that the obfuscated code is smaller than the original code. You can thank me later.
    </td></tr></table>
    <?  
  break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Change each `<?` into `<?php` or enable short open tags in your php configuration. Then try again if it works. It's a quick guess only.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion. Works great for me if I change `<?` to `<?php`.

Comment: I thought of that, but when I do, I get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampplite\htdocs\sitetest\encode.php on line 149

Comment: In addition to the short open tags, it looks like it's relying on `register_globals` on.

Comment: Nevermind. Got it now. Forgot to change all references. Doa!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change all `<?` to `<?php`.

Then break its reliance on `register_globals` with the following:

```
// Change this
//$b64_input=stripslashes($b64_input);
// To:
$b64_input=isset($_POST['b64_input']) ? stripslashes($_POST['b64_input']) : "";

// And below it, add:
$b64_action = isset($_POST['b64_action']) ? $_POST['b64_action'] : "";
```

Also, fix these short open tag dependencies:

```
Ln 43 - 44:
Input Length: <?php echo $ilength;?><br>
Output Length: <b><?php echo $olength;?></b><br>

Ln 67: <textarea rows=18 cols=60 name=done><?php echo $output;?></textarea>

Ln 105:  <textarea rows=18 cols=60 name=done><?php echo $output;?></textarea>

Ln 114 - 115:
Input Length: <?php echo $ilength;?><br>
Output Length: <b><?php echo $olength;?></b><br>
```

With the above changes, I was able to successfully obfuscate the obfuscator code.

Comment: +1 Thanks Michael for going above and beyond with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would honestly never use this code. Its just bad PHP and HTML code. (it seems like it might be old, due to the caps'ed HTML Tags and the reliance on global variables.)

If you want to just Base 64 Encode and decode it would be as easy as something like (off the top of my head):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Meh</title></head>
    <body>
       <form action="" method="POST">
          <select name="action">
              <option value="encode">Base64 Encode</option>
              <option value="decode">Base64 Decode</option>
          </select><br />
          <textarea name="content"></textarea><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Base64 It!" />
       </form>

    <?php
       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
           if($_POST['action'] == "decode")
                echo base64_decode($_POST['content']);
           else
                echo base64_encode($_POST['content'])
       }
     ?>
     </body>
</html>
```

This is just a rough example i just wrote, of course- but it should be enough, unless you are trying to do some more than that.

Shai.